# How sum of this series is equal to 1?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

Here is a problem in my hand-

> Show that
> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^n}{(1+e)(1+e^2) \cdots (1 + e^n)} = 1 
> $$

Some facts about this series can be easily observed. Let $a_n = \frac{e^n}{(1+e)(1+e^2) \cdots (1 + e^n)}$. Then

- $\lim_{ n \to \infty} a_n = 0$
- The series is convergent by ratio test.

How can I show the sum is $1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the $n$th term as $\frac{1+e^n}{(1+e)\cdots(1+e^n)}-\frac{1}{(1+e)\cdots(1+e^n)}=\frac{1}{(1+e)\cdots(1+e^{n-1})}-\frac{1}{(1+e)\cdots(1+e^n)}$, then telescope.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{e^n}{(1+e)(1+e^2) \cdots (1 + e^n)} = \frac{-1}{(1+e)(1+e^2) \cdots (1 + e^n)} + \frac{1}{(1+e)(1+e^2) \cdots (1 + e^{n-1})}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider generalization of this problem.

Let $a_n$ be sequence of positive numbers such that $ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n $ diverges.

Let $S_m = \sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{a_n}{b_n} $ where $b_n = (1 + a_1) \cdots (1+ a_n)$.
Then observe that

$
\frac{a_n}{b_n} = \frac{1}{b_{n-1}} - \frac{1}{b_n}
$

So $S_m = 1 - \frac{1}{b_m}$. Clearly as $m \to \infty$ we have sum equal $1$ since the product of $a_i + 1$ diverges to $ \infty$